# Sybase, execute string as sql query

Tags: string, sybase, execute

In Sybase SQL, I would like to execute a String containing SQL.

I would expect something like this to work

```
declare @exec_str char(100)
select @exec_str = "select 1"
execute @exec_str
go
```

from the  [documentation of the exec command](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands56.htm)

> execute | exec
>
> > ```
> > is used to execute a stored procedure or an extended stored
> > ```
> >
> > procedure (ESP). This keyword is
> >     necessary if there are multiple
> >     statements in the batch.
>
> execute is also used to execute a string containing Transact-SQL.

However my above example gives an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need bracketing:

```
execute ( @exec_str )
```